# How to look at ALL leading/lagging values in R

Tags: r, dplyr

So I'm trying to figure out how to determine if there is any data ahead of any given data point in a column. Or inversely, all rows lagging one with data. Currently, I have the following:

```
> df = data.frame(col = c(0,0,0,1,0))
> mutate(df, data_following = lead(col)>0)
  col data_following
1   0          FALSE
2   0          FALSE
3   0           TRUE
4   1          FALSE
5   0             NA
```

This tells me if there's data ONE row ahead for each row. I'd like to know if there's data in ANY of the rows ahead of each row (I.e. all the leading rows). My desired output would be:

```
> mutate(df, data_following = some_function(col))
  col data_following
1   0           TRUE
2   0           TRUE
3   0           TRUE
4   1          FALSE
5   0          FALSE
```

I could probably construct a loop or something, but I'd prefer something cleaner.. ideally that I can just plug into mutate(). I've tried taking a stab at this a few times but I've yet to come up with anything. Also, I'm working with a grouped data frame.. hopefully not relevant but worth mentioning.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check to see if the cumulative sum of the column is equal to the sum of the column, because if they are equal there are no more `1`'s left in the column.

```r
> df = data.frame(col = c(0,0,0,1,0))
> dplyr::mutate(df,data_following = !sum(col) == cumsum(col))

  col data_following
1   0           TRUE
2   0           TRUE
3   0           TRUE
4   1          FALSE
5   0          FALSE
```

Breaking it into steps might make the logic more intuitive:

```r
> dplyr::mutate(df,
                df_sum = sum(col),
                df_cumsum = cumsum(col),
                data_following = !df_sum == df_cumsum)

  col df_sum df_cumsum data_following
1   0      1         0           TRUE
2   0      1         0           TRUE
3   0      1         0           TRUE
4   1      1         1          FALSE
5   0      1         1          FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks! Great idea with cumsum(). It seems like in my case I'm effectively just looking for cumsum() == 0.. is there any reason I couldn't just do that and skip the sum()?

Comment: Nevermind, I realized of course that skipping the sum() requires the current and lagging rows to be empty, which will often not be the case

Comment: What you actually want is sort of a reverse cumsum, or a cumsum from the end of the table to the current line, equal to 0. You get to the "reverse" cumsum with `sum() - cumsum()`.